# Mouse and Keyboard not working on VirtualBox guest

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I set up an Ubuntu virtual machine through virtualbox.  Everything was fine until I troubleshooted copy/paste issues I was having.  I solved those issues by running `VBoxClient --clipboard` in the terminal. Note: Not sure that is connected to the issue.

The machine went to sleep mode, and now the keyboard and mouse no longer are able to interact with machine. I've tried restarting everything and also rebooting the host computer.  I've tried to SSH into the guest machine to find a workaround, but I'm getting this error:

```
 ssh_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort
```

I've spun up a clone of the VM, the same issue occurs.  I've spun up an alternate VM, the issue does NOT occur. Sort of at a lost on next steps.  I'll take any advice.  Thanks!